# Hibernate Polymorphic Queries

Tags: hibernate, hql, polymorphism

While reading Hibernate in Action(Christina Bauer & Gavin King) I came across the following section in chapter7

7.2.3 Polymorphic queries
We described HQL as an object-oriented query language, so it should support polymorphic queries—that is, queries for instances of a class and all instances of its subclasses, respectively. You already know enough HQL that we can demonstrate this. Consider the following query:

from BillingDetails

This query returns objects of the type BillingDetails, which is an abstract class. So, in this case, the concrete objects are of the subtypes of BillingDetails: CreditCard and BankAccount. If we only want instances of a particular subclass, we may use

from CreditCard

The class named in the from clause doesn’t need to be a mapped persistent class; any class will do. The following query returns all persistent objects:

from java.lang.Object

Of course, this also works for interfaces—this query returns all serializable persistent objects:

from java.io.Serializable

Criteria queries also support polymorphism:

session.createCriteria(BillingDetails.class).list();

This query returns instances of BillingDetails and its subclasses. Likewise, the following criteria query returns all persistent objects:

session.createCriteria(java.lang.Object.class).list();

Polymorphism applies not only to classes named explicitly in the from clause, but also to polymorphic associations, as you’ll see later.

**Question: What is the use of Polymorphic queries. How and when it is used.**

Comment: Isn't that obvious from what you posted? Say you want all the billing details, whatever their type is (credit card or bank account): you don't need to issue one w-query for each concrete subclass: a single query selecting BillingDetails is sufficient.

Answer (score -2):

java beats have posted a nice answer for polymorphic queries.

http://javabeat.net/implicit-polymorphism-hibernate/

**Update:** My bad, forgot to mention that they have used an example to explain polymorphic queries, here it goes:

Suppose we have two classes CreditCardPayment and DebitCardPayment and both of them extends the Payment superclass and each of these three classes have their own tables in database because table per class strategy has been used. At a point of time , If we want to retrieve the list of all the payments made via cash or card, below query would do the magic.

session.createCriteria(Payment.class).list();

While processing this criteria query, hibernate perform following operations –

Identify all the subclasses of payment, which are mapped to any table
Fire individual query to all of the tables
Combine the result of all the queries into list and return from hibernate layer

Although , hibernate does it internally but we really need only one query to fetch all the data of the both types of cards. Hence, the query used in hql are polymorphic.